# Erro No Final Do Loop (Bug delete com char*)

Tags: c++, ponteiro

1 - Tenho este código (Dei Uma Resumida, Digitem -1, E Depois 'n' Para Sair Do Loop E Acontecer O Erro):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#undef max
using namespace std;

int* cont = new int(0);

//-----------------------------------------// MAIN // -----------------------------------//

void main(){
    char* n = new char('s');

    while (*n == 's' || *n == 'S'){

        int* dinheiro = new int(500);

        while (*dinheiro >= 1){
            printf("Quanto Deseja Apostar ? ");
            scanf("%d%*c", &*dinheiro);

            printf("\nTentar Novamente (s-n) ? ");
            cin >> n;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
            system("cls");

        }
        delete dinheiro;
    }
    delete n;
}
```

E nessa parte:

```
printf("Tentar Novamente (s-n) ? ");
cin >> *n;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
system("cls");
```

Se o usuário não digitar 's' para voltar no loop ele da esse erro:

[image: Erro]

**Obs.:** Tirando os `delete` o programa funciona corretamente.

Comment: Não precisa se preocupar com cada byte. Acho pouco provável que trocar int por void vá economizar qualquer coisa. Retornar um int é uma das coisas mais simples que um programa costuma fazer, pois o valor é retornado dentro de um registrador do processador.

Comment: Você está se afligindo pelas coisas erradas ;-) Mas se ainda assim quiser se afligir com isso, sugiro que faça o disassembly do código gerado (com e sem otimizações, para comparar), e compare os resultados. Também rode uns benchmarks para medir tempo e uso de memória. Se notar alguma diferença eu engulo meu diploma (<- isso é figura de linguagem, haha)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Resolvi de uma forma simples: em vez de `char* n` vou usar `string* n`. Pronto, o `delete` não buga

Consegui resolver a `void DimDim()`

Agora ela ficou assim `void DimDim(__int8 pos, int* numeros)`

E para chamar ela eu faço assim: `DimDim(3, &numeros[0]);`

Depois de pesquisar bem, entendi um pouco mais sobre o operador [] então consegui :D

Comment: O Que Quer Que Eu Aprenda ?

Comment: A usar ponteiros. A minha dica não resolveu? Nem sei se você tentou ela.

Comment: @marcus Eu Mudei De char Pra String Não Precisou Da Sua Dica E Estou Dando Um +1 Na Sua Resposta Por Tentar Ajudar Obrigado

Comment: A Minha Resposta Foi Útil Para Min Mesmo E Povo Da -1... Não Da Para Entender O SOpt... , Na Resposta Do Amigo A Baixo Não Foi Resolvido O Meu Problema Mas Ele Tem +2 Um Foi Eu Que Dei Porque N Tenho Dó De Clicar Na Seta Para Cima, O Cara Tento Ajuda E Reconheço.

Comment: Não esquenta carinha, vai participando da comunidade que você vai pegando os macetes e entendendo como a coisa funciona. #PareDeEscreverAssim

Answer (score 4):

Veja a linha:

```
cin >> n;
```

A variável `n` é do tipo char*, então o operador >> pensa que há um array alocado ali, e lê coisas que não cabem no buffer ("-1" tem 2 chars). Nem há buffer, porque você alocou dinamicamente apenas 1 char (para treinar, OK, num programa de verdade, parece sem propósito).

Sugiro que troque então por:

```
cin >> *n;
```

ou

```
scanf("%c", n);
```

Se digitar -1, a linha acima (qualquer uma) lerá apenas o "-", sem gravar fora do espaço alocado.

Outra coisa: `&*dinheiro` é meio inútil. Os operadores & e * se cancelam (na ausência de operator overloading), e seria o mesmo que escrever apenas `dinheiro`.

E uma importante lição no mundo do C e C++: o fato do compilador aceitar está muito vagamente relacionado com o fato do programa estar correto.

Comment: A Questão É Que Isso Não Resolve O Meu Código De Verdade Vou Deixa-ló Aki Para Poder Acessa-ló: [Código](http://codepad.org/g0LxEImi)

Comment: OK, apontei onde vi um erro e não postei a solução. Já editei para corrigir isso.
Obs.: seja perfeccionista aqui também e escreva "deixá-lo" e "acessá-lo", com o acento no lugar certo ;-)

Comment: Sobre a questão do parâmetro `numeros` para DimDim, na verdade não há nada complicado, é só passar: DimDim(0, numeros)... E se quiser mesmo ponteiro pra ponteiro é só usar **.

Comment: Eu só achei que eu não precisasse dizer isto, mas para pegar o endereço de uma variável é só usar o operador `&`:
__int8 alguma_pos = 0;
DimDim(&alguma_pos, numeros);

Comment: Eu Sei Disso Mas (&0) Não Funciona Né, A Maior Questão Que Eu Quero É Essa: Como Criar Uma Ponteiro -> `void DimDim(__int8 pos, ( int* dinheiro[] <- ISSO DAKI ) )` E Como Eu Passaria Esse Parâmetro

Comment: Exato. Por isso eu coloquei o jeito certo de fazer, colocando numa variável temporária. Pegar o "endereço do zero" não faz sentido. Imagina se você atribui algo para o valor apontado por esse ponteiro e muda o valor do zero? hahahaha

Comment: Tudo Bem Esquece O Primeiro Parâmetro E Foca No Segundo.

Comment: Meu último comentário: `void DimDim(__int8 pos, int** dinheiro);` é chamado com: `int* coisas = new int[9]; DimDim(0, &coisas)`. Obs.: Troquei o `int* dinheiro[]` por `int**` de propósito.